# What is the best way to convert Action<T> to Func<T,Tres>?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have two functions in my class with this signatures,

```
public static TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> remoteCall);
public static void Execute(Action<T> remoteCall)
```

How can I pass the same delegate in the second method to the first one? Creating method with Delegate argument is not a way, because I am losing some exception information.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Wrap it in a delegate of type `Func<T, TResult>` with a dummy return value, e.g.

```
public static void Execute(Action<T> remoteCall)
{
    Execute(t => { remoteCall(t); return true; });
}
```

Comment: important to note that this is trading off the code reuse vs. an extra instance due to the closure that lambda is making on the remoteCall argument.

Answer (score 9):

you are asking literally to pass something that doesn't supply a result to a function that requires it.
This is nonsensical.

You can easily convert any function of Form `Action<T>` to `Func<T,TResult>` if you are willing to supply some result value (either implicitly or explicitly)

```
Func<T,TResult> MakeDefault<T,TResult>(Action<T> action)
{
    return t =>  { action(t); return default(TResult);}; 
}
```

or

```
Func<T,TResult> MakeFixed<T,TResult>(Action<T> action, TResult result)
{
    return t =>  { action(t); return result; };
}
```

Comment: It is "nonsensical" only from C# point of view. There are languages that handle voids gracefully.