# Use func method for an action also?

Tags: c#, action, func

I created a method to abstract try/catch functionality. I have about 30 methods that have this exact same try/catch scenario. So I put it in one method:

```
    private T Invoke<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return func.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw LogAndThrowFaultException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Now, most of the methods call it like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<PingResponse> GetAllForPingRequest(PingRequest pingRequest)
    {
        return Invoke(() => PingResponseLogic.GetAllForPingRequest(pingRequest));
    }
```

My issue is that I have just a couple of methods that call it without needing to return a value:

```
Invoke<void>(() => CustomVariableGroupLogic.Delete(customVariableGroup));
```

However, I can't use `void` there. The `Invoke()` method takes a `func`, but in this case it needs to be an `action`. I did some research and it looks like I may have to create another `Invoke()` method, but have it take an action. Those suggestions were from 2009 and 2010 though. Is it possible to somehow use my func method without having to create another `Invoke()` method like `Invoke2()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One quick and dirty solution would be to add **default** value after calling `Delete` method. It will be ignored anyway, if you don't assign result of the `Invoke` method to a variable. For instance, next code demonstrates this:

```
Invoke(() => {CustomVariableGroupLogic.Delete(customVariableGroup); return 0; });
```

You can see similar example proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/943955/1283124),

If you have lots and lots of such calls, you can build a fancy wrapper, that will return `Func` for a given `Action`. Example:

```
Func<Action, Func<int>> wrap = action => () => {action(); return 0;};
```

now you can

```
Invoke(() => wrap(() => CustomVariableGroupLogic.Delete(customVariableGroup)));
```

but this goes a little bit close to lambda craziness

**Inspired by pcm2**:

you can create an overload to `Invoke`, that simply takes `Action` as a parameter, use solution proposed above to call implementation with `Func<T>`:

```
public void Invoke(Action action)
{
    Invoke(() => {action(); return 0;});
}
```

now you simply can

```
Invoke(() => CustomVariableGroupLogic.Delete(customVariableGroup));
```

Comment: Ha. I was looking for tips like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you not just create an overload of invoke?

```
public void Invoke<T>(Func<T> func){
    return (T) InvokeInternal(func);
}

public void Invoke(Action action){
    InvokeInternal(action);
}
```

If you'd then want both methods to do the exact same thing, and keeping things DRY, you could create a method like so:

```
private object InvokeInternal(System.Delegate @delegate)
{
    try
    {
        return @delegate.DynamicInvoke();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw LogAndThrowFaultException(ex);
    }
}
```

And have both your overloads calling this method, appropriately casting the result, if any

Comment: Note that the overload taking an `Action` could just call the overload taking a `Func`: `Invoke<int>(() => { action(); return 0; });`

Comment: Indeed, but that would look a little sketchy, don't you think? If I encountered code like that, i would have to stop and think for a second

Comment: I would *far* rather have that code than the dynamic code, which loses type safety for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you really have to `func.Invoke()`? Why not just `func()`?
2. Why isn't your `Invoke` static?
3. Depending on what `LogAndThrowFaultException` is doing, this could be pretty bad. Make sure that the exception stack is preserved by always setting the inner exception to `ex`.

But yes, you need a second function that returns void instead of T.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the action into a func like so. Or you can create a convenience function that does the wrapping:

```
void Main()
{
    Action<string> a = s => Console.WriteLine(s);

    Invoke(() => { a(); return null; });
    Invoke(s);
}

private void Invoke(Action a)
{
    Invoke(() => { a(); return null; };
}
```

Comment: Either specify a type argument or use a `return` value that will allow the compiler to infer the type argument - returning null isn't won't work.

Comment: You could `return 0;` or `return (object)null;`.