# Is there a generic way of defining a method that receives neither an Action or a Func<Task>?

Tags: c#, async-await, action, func

I have a method `A` that wraps the execution of another method `B` by running some logic before and after it. The method `B` could be a Task or not. So in order to be able to `await` when the method `B` is task I had to implement twice the `A` method like this:

```
public async Task A(int id, Action<int> b)
{
    try
    {
        await BeforeAsync(id);
        b(id);
        await AfterAsync(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Handle(ex, id);
    }
}

public async Task A(int id, Func<int,Task> b)
{
    try
    {
        await BeforeAsync(id);
        await b(id);
        await AfterAsync(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Handle(ex, id);
    }
}
```

Is there a way of avoiding the duplication?

Comment: The BCL and every other library just duplicates it.

Comment: @Progman the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943941/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-actiont-to-funct-tres) is actually a different question, with an answer that is not applicable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, assuming silly things like passing an object and testing it with casts counts :)

What about this?

```
public Task A(int id, Action<int> b) => A(id, x => { b(a); return Task.CompletedTask; });
```

That way you're not duplicating code.

Comment: Good one. I didn't thought about that option. Thanks!!

Comment: I hope it's not performance critical, because it adds another delegate invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is:

```
public async Task A(int id, Delegate b)
{
    try
    {
        await BeforeAsync(id);
        if (b.DynamicInvoke(id) is Task task) await task;
        await AfterAsync(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Handle(ex, id);
    }
}
```

But now you lost type safety (because you can pass any delegate) and gained nothing.

There's a reason for `Task.Run` having 8 overloads: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=task.run

Comment: Yeah, loosing the type safety will make the code quite hard to maintain

Answer (score 0):

Use RX observer pattern implementation.

```
source.Subscribe(o => Log.Write($"On Next {o}"));
```

or if you specify additional pre- and post conditions

```
source
  .Do(_ => Log.Write("Before"))
  .Finally(()=> Log.Write("After"))
  .Subscribe(
    o => Log.Write($"On Next {o}"),
    exception => Log.Write($"On Error {exception}")
    () => Log.Write("On Completed"));
```

The problem with

```
try
{
    await BeforeAsync(id);
    b(id);
    await AfterAsync(id);
}
```

is that you would assume that the following Catch will actually catch all the exceptions, but that is not the case, and it happens only if you wait or await for it. Simply put, it is way more complex to do it properly.